# Set Jtable cell editable ONLY upon selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable and I added a DefaultTabelModel to it. I created a popup menu that appears when users right click on a cell in the table. One of the items in the menu is "Rename." How can I make the selected cell editable when the Rename item is clicked? I have set up all the elements and the only missing piece here is making THE selected cell editable.

The `isCellEditable(row, col)` method in the DefaultTableModel is not helpful here because it sets a cell's editability based on its position (i.e. row and column) in the table, not the selection status of a cell.

I suspect that I will need TableCellEditor, but I am not sure how to use it. I would really appreciate a sample code on how to make this happen and/or explanations of how to use TableCellEditor for this purpose. Thank you in advance!!

Relevant pieces of my code:

```java
class DataListTable extends JTable
    mouseReleased(): 
        int row = this.getSelectedRow();
        popupmenu.show(this, event.getX(), event.getY());

class RenameDataMenuItem 
    actionPerformed():
    //want to get the (row, col) of the selected cell here and make it editable
```

Comment: [`JTable#editCellAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#editCellAt(int,int)) is where you need to start, but you may also need to change the table model to make the cell editable in the first place - probably through some kind of flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the selected cell editable when the Rename item is clicked?

The `isCellEditable(...)` method will determine if the cell can be edited via the table editor.

You can still change the data in the model by using the `setValueAt(..)` method of the `JTable` or the `TableModel`.

So what you can do is in your rename menu item you can display a `JOptionPane` to prompt for the new value. Then you just manually save the value using either of the above methods.

Comment: I really like the JOptionPane idea. Successfully implemented it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
public class MyTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

JComponent component = new JTextField();

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return ((JTextField)component).getText();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

    if(isSelected) {
        ((JTextField)component).setText((String)value);
    }
    return component;
}

}
```